# How to read from a file block by block

Tags: java, io, iterator, bufferedreader

I need to process a large text file and because there are always several numbers of lines from which I want to get information which also depend on each other, I wanted to read the file block by block, rather than storing only specific features from some lines above.

Every block would be indicated by a unique symbol in the first line of it.

Is it possible with some kind of iterator and then check if my symbol appears at each line? i really do not have any great ideas how to handle this, so help would be very much appreciated.

Example:

```
a1    $    12    20    namea1
b1    x    12    15    namea1,nameb1
c1    x    13    17    namea1,namec1
d1    x    18    20    namea1,named1
a2    $    36    55    namea2
b2    x    38    40    namea2,nameb2
c2    x    46    54    namea2,namec2
```

As you can see all lines after the line with symbol `$` refer to this line in some way, the numbers are in between the distance from line a1 and the names are always combined. I thought it might be better to read a file like this block by block rather than line by line.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read how to ask a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Leviand I think the question is pretty clear; at least I understood the point from one pass

Comment: @Eugene clear? No content of files he's referring to, no symbol he's referring to. How can you see a clear question here? And btw I'm just suggesting him how to make his question better.

Comment: @Leviand *I understood*, emphasize on *I*; may be you do have a valid point though

Comment: Please see edits to answer for a more clear example of what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "block-by-block", and even having said that, your text file structure seems well suited for line-by-line analysis.  So based on your file structure, you could simply parse it in a basic while loop. Pseudo-code:

```
While not end of file
    Read line into a String
    split this String on whatspace, "\\s+" into a String array
    Check the String held by the 2nd item in the String array, item[1] 
    Do action with line (create a certain object) based on this String
end of file
```

Now if one of the symbols represent a heading of some sort, and if that is what you mean by block-by-block, then all you would need to do is alter your parsing strategy, using a state-dependent handling of your object, something like SAX parsing. So, if for instance `"$"` indicates a new "block", then create a new block, and within the while loop, create objects to put into this block, until a new one is encountered.

So assuming a text file looking like:

```
$    12    20    namea1
x    12    15    namea1,nameb1
x    13    17    namea1,namec1
x    18    20    namea1,named1
$    36    55    namea2
x    38    40    namea2,nameb2
x    46    54    namea2,namec2
```

I'm assuming that the first symbol you show is not really in the file

And assuming you have a class called Line looking something like:

```
public class Line {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private List<String> names  = new ArrayList<>();

    public Line(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", names=" + names + "]";
    }

}
```

And a Block class,...

```
public class Block {
    private String name;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public Block(String name, int x, int y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addLine(Line line) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Block [name=" + name + ", x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", lines=" + lines + "]";
    }

}
```

You could parser it like so:

```
Scanner blockScanner = new Scanner(resource);

Block currentBlock = null;
while (blockScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = blockScanner.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

    // NEW_BLOCK == "$"
    if (tokens[0].equals(NEW_BLOCK)) {
        currentBlock = createBlockFromTokens(tokens);
        blocks.add(currentBlock);
    } else if (currentBlock != null) {
        currentBlock.addLine(createLineFromTokens(tokens));
    }
}
```

Where the `createXxxxFromTokens(tokens)` creates a new line or new block from the String array

---

For example, the whole thing as a single MCVE:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadBlocks {
    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "blocks.txt";
    private static final String NEW_BLOCK = "$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();

        InputStream resource = ReadBlocks.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_PATH);
        Scanner blockScanner = new Scanner(resource);

        Block currentBlock = null;
        while (blockScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = blockScanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            if (tokens[0].equals(NEW_BLOCK)) {
                currentBlock = createBlockFromTokens(tokens);
                blocks.add(currentBlock);
            } else if (currentBlock != null) {
                currentBlock.addLine(createLineFromTokens(tokens));
            }
        }

        if (blockScanner != null) {
            blockScanner.close();
        }

        for (Block block : blocks) {
            System.out.println(block);
        }
    }

    private static Line createLineFromTokens(String[] tokens) {
        if (tokens.length < 4) {
            // throw exception
        }
        int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);

        Line line = new Line(x, y);
        String[] names = tokens[3].split(",");
        for (String name : names) {
            line.addName(name);
        }
        return line;
    }

    private static Block createBlockFromTokens(String[] tokens) {
        if (tokens.length < 4) {
            // throw exception
        }
        int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        String name = tokens[3];
        return new Block(name, x, y);
    }
}
```

```
class Block {
    private String name;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public Block(String name, int x, int y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addLine(Line line) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Block [name=" + name + ", x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", lines=" + lines + "]";
    }

}
```

```
class Line {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public Line(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", names=" + names + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the big input!
will look into what suits the problem best.
Thanks a lot